# Losing values along a macro loop

Tags: loops, macros, sas

I have a data set with return differences of 20 pairs of stocks abd as well their price differences and for each pair a trigger value over 125 days. Now I want to do some calculations to get a data set where I have for each pair the total return but along the way I somehow loose my values. So far I get an output data set with the name of my all my pairs as variables but always missing values.
So first i put the names of the price deviation, trigger and return deviation variables into three macro vars. Then i create my data set where had the values of the in total 60 variables.
MY data set "all" looks like this

```
date         trigger1 trigger2 ...... trigger20 pricedev1 pricedev2....... returndev1 returndev2 ......... returndev20
21/11/2002    0.04    0.23                       -0.12    .                  0.0012      .                    .    
.             0.04    o.23                        0.34
.              .        .                          .
.              .        .             
28/04/2004    0.04    0.23    ...                 0.11   .....                                              -0.23
```

I created the macro vars with proc sql from different data sets.They include the variable names as trigger1, trigger2 and so on or pricedev1 pricedev2 and so on or returndev1, retundev2 and so on. And that's what i did:

```
  data all;
   if _n_=1 then set trigger;
   set ba.trade1_pdev;
  run;

  data all;
  merge all ba.trade1_rdev;
  run;



   Proc transpose data=all out=data1 (rename=(_name_=var));
   by date;
   run;
```

Then I created a macro:

```
  %macro totret (dsname);

  %do d=1 %to 20;

  %let pair=%trim(%scan(&pairname.,&d.," "));
  %let ret=%trim(%scan(&ret.,&d.," "));
  %let trigger=%trim(%scan(&trigger.,&d.," "));

  data pair;
  set data1;
  length all $20;
  if var="&pair." then all="pdev";
  else if var="&trigger." then all="trigger"; 
  else if var="&ret." then all="rdev";
  else delete;
  drop var;
  run;

  proc sort data=pair;
  by date;
  quit;

  proc transpose data=pair out=pair;
  by date;
  id all;
  quit;


  data pair;
  set pair;
  ivar=0;
  if pdev>=trigger then ivar=1;
  if pdev<=-1*trigger then ivar=-1;
  run;

  data pair;
  set pair;
  totret=ivar*rdev;
  keep date totret;
  run;

  data pair;
  set pair;
  rename totret=&pair.;
  run;

  proc sort data=pair;
  by date;
  quit;

  proc transpose data=pair out=pair (rename=(_name_=var));
  by date;
  quit;


  %if &d.=1 %then %do;

  data &dsname.;
  set pair;
  run;

  %end;


  %if &d.>1 %then %do;

  data &dsname.;
  set &dsname. pair;
  run;

  %end;



  %end;

  %mend totret;
  %totret (tot_ret);
```

Then I transpose it back again, but the result is dataset with 20 variables and the date variable but all of the 20 vars have no values.

```
  proc sort data=tot_ret;
  by date;
  quit;

  Proc transpose data=tot_ret out=test;
  by date;
  id var;
  quit;
```

in my resulting data set I want to have:

```
date        totret1   totret2     ...........     totret20
21/11/2002      .        .                           .
.             
.              .        .                            .
.              .        .             
28/04/2004      .      .                             .
```

But just with the correct values ;)

Comment: You are not showing any values for the macro variables you a %scanning.

Comment: but at this step I do not want the values I want the stock names in the macro, since it is transposed at that point. I wrote the code first for just one stock pair and it worked. But not since I turned it into the macro loop

Comment: You can define those macro variables external to the macro, but you need to include example values for them in your question.  Similarly it would help to post example input data and desired results.

Comment: Sorry I missunderstood your comment a little bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process of looping 20 times doing the same actions of transpose, simple manipulation, transpose, and stacking results indicates you can probably use arrays.  If I understand the process, there is **no need for a macro** that runs each stock, one at a time through many gyrations.

Sample code (untested) that uses arrays:

```
data want;
  set all end=end;
  by date; * for safety, cause error if rows are not in date order;

  array TRIGGERS trigger1-trigger20;
  array PRICEDEVS price1-price20;
  array RETURNDEVS returndev1-returndev20;
  array IVARS ivar1-ivar20;
  array TOTRETS totret1-totret20;

  * process all 20 stocks price info on a day;
  do index = 1 to 20;
    if PRICEDEVS[index] >= TRIGGERS[index] then
      IVARS[index] = 1
    else
    if PRICEDEVS[index] <= -TRIGGERS[index] then
      IVARS[index] = -1;

    TOTRETS[index] = IVARS[index] * RETURNDEVS[index];
  end;
  keep date totret1-totret20;
run;
```

If I have misunderstood the question my apologies.

For future handling of this kind of data, consider not adding a new column for new stocks.  Consider instead switching to a categorical shape of data that has columns `stock`, `date`, `trigger`, `pricedev`, `returndev`, `totret` -- simple WHERE statements could then easily select stocks and date ranges of interest.

** ADDED **

For the case of semantically named columns that follow a naming pattern for trigger, pricedev, returndev and totret you can use a macro to generate the source code for the variables that are the array elements.  For instance,

- a stocks trigger value on date concept: variable name is always _t
- a stocks pricedev value on date concept: variable name is always
- a stocks return_dev value on date concept: variable name is always _r
- a stocks totret value on date concept: variable name is always _totret

However, if you intend to increase the sophistication of the process, the utility of the structure you are working with now decreases.

Example of a `totret` macro that handles different sets of stocks.

```
%let stocks = BNNESR CNNESR XYZFOO ACHOO SYNOJ;
... data gather process for stocks creates ALL ...
%totret (data=all, id=mrX_set1, stocks=&stocks)

%let stocks = GGL IBM ABC MSFT ORCL;
... data gather process for stocks creates ALL ...
%totret (data=all, id=mrX_set2, stocks=&stocks)
```

The macro being called would be an abstraction (templated version) of the earlier DATA step.  When invoked that macro generates the source code of a specific DATA step.  The macro would look something like the following (untested):

```
%macro totret (data=, id=, stocks=, out=totret_&id);

  %local trigger_vars pricedev_vars returndev_vars totret_vars;
  %local i stock;

  %* use macro to build up variable name lists;
  %* the variable names for the concepts of
  %* trigger, pricedev, returndev, and totret
  %* must follow the expected naming conventions;

  %let i = 1;
  %do %while (%length(%scan(&stocks,&i)) > 0);
    %let stock = %scan(&stocks,&i);
                                          * naming convention;
                                          * VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV;
    %let trigger_vars   = &trigger_vars   &stock._t;
    %let pricedev_vars  = &pricedev_vars  &stock;
    %let returndev_vars = &returndev_vars &stock._r;
    %let totret_vars    = &totret_vars    &stock._totret;

    %let i = %eval (&i + 1);
  %end;

  data &OUT;
    set &DATA end=end;
    by date; * for safety, cause error if rows are not in date order;

    array TRIGGERS   &trigger_vars;
    array PRICEDEVS  &pricedev_vars;
    array RETURNDEVS &returndev_vars;
    array TOTRETS    &totret_vars;
    * array IVARS ivar1-ivar20; * does not need to be arrayified;

    * process all 20 stocks price info on a day;
    do index = 1 to DIM(TRIGGERS);
      if PRICEDEVS[index] >= TRIGGERS[index] then
        IVARS = 1
      else
      if PRICEDEVS[index] <= -TRIGGERS[index] then
        IVARS = -1;

      TOTRETS[index] = IVARS * RETURNDEVS[index];
    end;

    keep date &totret_vars;
  run;
%mend;
```

NOTE: The data gather process should also leverage of the abstraction of a run_id and list of stocks being processed in the run.

You might also find utility in managing the conditions of multiple sets of run-through parameters in a control dataset similar to the following:

```
run_id, index, stock
mrX_set1, 1, BNNESR
mrX_set1, 2, CNNESR
mrX_set1, 3, XYZFOO
mrX_set1, 4, ACHOO
mrX_set1, 5, SYNOJ
...
mrX_set2, 1, GGL
...
mrX_set2, 5, ORCL
```

Again, long term, consider refactoring the data stuctures so that they have stock as a categorical concept.

Comment: thank you very much. But the problem is the variables are not actually called trigger1 or privedev1 but have the actual pairname like my one of my trigger is BNNESR_t and the retdev of the pair is called BNNESR_r and the pricedev BNNESR and so i had to type what the arry includes for all 20 pairs. that is doable

Comment: But i will run the whole code I have which is much more also 25 times and will probably always get different pairs and so on different names. Hence it woulb be the best if it runs like i have the idea so I can just save the totrets in 25 different data sets

Comment: Just replace the list of variables in the ARRAY statements with the space delimited list of variable names that you were using in your macro. `array triggers &trigger;`

Comment: thank you! had the same idea just the minute posted my comment :D

Comment: thank you very much, Richard. If I understand your code you also show me how to rename my variables so i get the bnnesr_t or bnnesr_r?? But i did this already so i have the names with the addtion of _r and _t already stored in macros. It is a little bit difficult to explain what I already did, because my code is pretty long (if i print it its 13 pages) and actually this calculation would be the last step. Since i already put them  into  macro vars, i tried it with the array version but i get an error that the array subscript is out of range

Comment: `data totret;
set all;

 array triggers &trigger;
 array pricedev &pairname;
 array retdev &ret;
 array totrets &totret;

 do i=1 to dim(triggers);
  ivar=0;
  if pricedev(i)>= triggers(i) then ivar=1;
  else if pricedev(i)<=-triggers(i) then ivar=-1;

 totrets(i)=ivar*retdev(i);
end;
keep date &totret;
run;´

Comment: The do loop goes from 1 to DIM(triggers).  triggers is an array of the trigger variables, what ever they are.  This means there must be the same number of variables for each concept.  Out of range tells me one of the arrays does not have enough variables associated with it. What do you see if you add macro %put statements for logging purposes (%put NOTE: &=trigger; %put NOTE: &=pairname; %put NOTE: &=ret;).  Better yet, use OPTIONS MPRINT before the macro call and add the LOG showing the generated code to the question.